# Python function not working a second time

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def equip(item):
    x = True
    while x == True:
        if len(bag_sword) > 1:
            print "You can't have 2 weapons equipped!"
            break
        if len(bag_chest) > 1:
            print "You can't have 2 chestplates equipped!"
            break
        if len(bag_gloves) > 1:
            print "You can't have 4 gloves equipped!"
            break
        if len(bag_helmet) > 1:
            print "You can't have 2 helmets equipped!"
            break

        if item == "iron sword" and "iron sword" in bag:
            print "\nYou equip the Iron Sword"
            bag.remove("iron sword")
            bag_sword.append("iron sword")
            break
```

Whenever I run this function a second time after I put "iron sword" into one of the `bag_`s, and try to add another to test it, it doesn't do anything and the code completely freezes.

The `bag_`s are all lists.

My guess was the while loop was stuck and it wasn't changing the length whenever I put something into the list in-game, because that's not how the language works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you added a sword to the bag, none of your conditions are true. Your `len(bag_sword)` is exactly 1, (so `if len(bag_sword) > 1:` won't be matched), and `'iron sword' in bag` is false.

Because none of your `if` statements match, no `break` is executed and your `while` loop goes on forever.

You don't want to test if there is more than one item in your `bag_sword`. Test if there is **any** item in that bag:

```
if bag_sword:  # true if not empty
    print "You can't have 2 weapons equipped!"
    break
```

because you are testing *before* adding a second weapon.

Answer (score 0):

The entire code is nonsense. 
First of all, you are dealing with lists and not dictionaries.

You DON'T have in Python "break" keyword. In Python exist if, elif and else keywords.

item is the parameter you pass in the function.

the keyword len(['item','two'])
gives as a resultset 2,
lists have only values and the elements are fetched by number in the list.

example:
mylist = ['hello','world']

print mylist[0] results in 'hello'

get yourself more familiar with builtin types:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Here is some sample code:

```
bag_s = {'bag_sword':0,'bag_chest':0,'bag_gloves':0,'bag_helmet':0,'iron sword':0}

def equip(item):
   its = item.keys()    
   for itx in its:        
     if itx == 'bag_sword':
       if item[itx] > 1:
          print 'you can\'t have 2 weapons erquipped'            

      elif itx == 'bag_chest':
        if item[itx] > 1:
            print 'you can\'t have 2 weapons erquipped'

      elif itx == 'bag_gloves':
        if item[itx] > 1:
            print 'you can\'t have 2 weapons erquipped'

      elif itx == 'bag_helmet':
        if item[itx] > 1:
            print 'you can\'t have 2 weapons erquipped'            


      elif itx == 'iron sword':
        if item[itx] > 1:
            print 'you can\'t have 2 weapons erquipped'


      if item[itx] == 1:
        bag_s[itx]+=1


equip({'bag_sword':1})

print bag_s
```

Comment: I ignored this for awhile because I had no idea what it was, but I've been reading more into Python and this helped a lot, thank you.